# reuse UITableViewCell with diferent data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have 2 arrays with different data

```
var array : [String] = ["getMeals", "getMeasure", "getWorkouts"]
var array2 : [String] = ["getStep", "getStep", "getStep"]
```

I am trying to retrieve the images from arrays, but in different collection cells.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if indexPath.section == 0{
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "WorkoutCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! WorkoutCollectionCell
        cell.collectionImage.image = UIImage(named: array[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }else{
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "WorkoutCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! WorkoutCollectionCell
                   cell.collectionImage.image = UIImage(named: array2[indexPath.row])
                   return cell
    }

}
```

I need to create another UICollectionViewCell or I can use the current cell?

Comment: The short answer is yes,  Dequeue the cell first, assign content based on whatever criteria you want, then return the cell.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the same cell, with this code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "WorkoutCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! WorkoutCollectionCell
    if indexPath.section == 0{

        cell.collectionImage.image = UIImage(named: array[indexPath.row])

    }else{

        cell.collectionImage.image = UIImage(named: array2[indexPath.row])

    }
 return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need 1 array like

```
let array  = [["getMeals", "getMeasure", "getWorkouts"],["getStep", "getStep", "getStep"]]

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int { 
    return array.count
} 
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int { 
    return array[section].count 
} 
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell { 
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "WorkoutCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! WorkoutCollectionCell
    cell.collectionImage.image = UIImage(named: array[indexPath.section][indexPath.row])
    return cell  
}
```

Comment: but now I have 2 collectionViewCells with 6 images

Comment: where are the 2 ? you only dequeue 1 with id `WorkoutCollectionCell`

Comment: you can't use collection cell for table and vice versa